# Foreach not displaying the Results

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, wordpress

Hi am using the following Query  need to get the `order_id` and `product_id` from this query ,
well when I run the query in phpmyadmin results are displayed.

```
global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT oi.order_id, p.ID as product_id, p.post_title, p.post_author as seller_id,
                oim2.meta_value as order_total, terms.name as order_status
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items oi
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim ON oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim2 ON oim2.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON oim.meta_value = p.ID
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} rel ON oi.order_id = rel.object_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tax ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
            WHERE
                oim.meta_key = '_product_id' AND
                oim2.meta_key = '_line_total'
            GROUP BY oi.order_id";

    $orders = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    if ( $orders ) {
        foreach ($orders as $order) {

            $result=customFunction(**$order->order_id,$order->product_id,$order->seller_id**);

          }
```

the problem is `$order->order_id` and `$order->product_id` value is not getting passed to the function but only `$order->seller_id` is getting passed. But in phpmyadmin the values are present for all the three variables.

tried

```
echo $orders[product_id] ;
echo   $orders[order_id] ;
echo   $orders[seller_id];
```

Hut only `echo   $orders[seller_id];` shows the value.

Here is the array structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [order_id] => 2774
        [product_id] => 2531
        [post_title] => Klassic Koalas Mug
        [seller_id] => 3
        [order_total] => 12
        [order_status] => cancelled
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [order_id] => 2869
        [product_id] => 2622
        [post_title] => Mug, Aqua
        [seller_id] => 1
        [order_total] => 1
        [order_status] => on-hold
    )
```

Comment: Your echo statements definitely wouldn't work. $orders will be a collection, in this case an array of objects. Dump $orders and see what you get.

Comment: What are the 2 `**` for in the function call?? Where are you coding the echo's you say do not work??

Comment: $result=customFunction(**$order->order_id,$order->product_id,$order->seller_id**); the 2** are have select the echo and pressed cntrl +B to make it bold . but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Do:

```
var_dump($orders)
```

and see what's inside. Maybe they are fetched as 'oi.order_id'.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about `product_id`, but it seems that `order_id` is not showing up because you are not setting and alias for `order_id`. So take this:

```
SELECT oi.order_id,
```

And change it to this

```
SELECT oi.order_id as order_id,
```

Past that do a dump of `$orders` to see the overall structure like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($orders);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets debug this first, var_dump is your friend! try :

```
$orders = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
var_dump($orders); die();
```

Now, after adding the var_dump, check the result, if order_id and product_id still don't have result, might be there is a DB issue? Then you have to fix your DB first.